# ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: An error occurred while sending the request. User error 2011

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Hi I have the above error coming up when accessing storage container folder where I am trying to get the metadata of a folder and its files. It can't access the folders for some reason. checked linked service and storage container where public access is enabled and private end point is also set.

Please let me know what else is missing.

Comment: can you add which authentication you are trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the error and got similar error.

[image]

**The cause of error was the I am trying to access the ADLS gen 2 which is not available or present.**

After providing correct information I am successfully able to connect ADLS Gen 2

[image]